# printf format error

Tags: java, string-formatting

My value won't print due to an "illegal format conversion exception". I'm wondering how to fix this.

Here’s my code:

```
double n = 0;
System.out.printf("%10d", n);
```

Comment: `"%d"` is for integral types. Use `"%f"` for floating-point values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"%d"` is for integral types. Use `"%f"` for floating-point values:

```
double n = 0.0d;
System.out.printf("%10f", n);
```

For more information about String formatter rules, check [its official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: This is surely a dupe of the earlier answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `%f` for floating-point value, instead of `%d`, which is only for integers.

So your original code could be look like this one:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.printf("%-10s %10s %n", "Term", "Value");

    double pi = 0;

    for (int i = 1, div = 1; i <= 20; i++, div += 2)
        System.out.printf("%-10d %10f\n", i, pi = i % 2 == 0 ? pi - 4. / div : pi + 4. / div);
}
```